# how to check multiple conditions at the same time

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation, input

I have a function where I check the length and wether the input isnt empty, 
I would like to know if its possible to check at the same time wether the input is a number or not. 
Im looking for something like this: if (field.value.length > 0 && isNaN)

```
function checkNotEmpty(field,span){

                    if (field.value.length > 0){
                    document.getElementById(span).className='ok'
                    document.getElementById(span).innerHTML='its ok';

                    }
                    else {
                    document.getElementById(span).className='notok'
                    document.getElementById(span).innerHTML='its not ok';

                    }
                }
```

Comment: it shouldnt be a number and the input should be greater then 0 so he input  shouldnt be empty,

Comment: Ahh, read that wrong, my mistake

Comment: So you don't know how to check if its a number or not?

Comment: You already have it. `isNaN(field.value)` will give you a boolean value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, it appears you already have your answer.

```
if (field.value.length > 0 && isNaN(field.value)) {
    //...value is at least 1 character long and field IS not a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
function checkNotEmpty(field, span) {
  let value = parseInt(field.value);
  if (isNaN(value) || value < 0) {
    // Either it's not a number or it's negative.
    // React appropriately.
  } else {
    // We're good.
  }
}
```